# Will upgrading to Mac OS X 10.12 break my newly installed QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, mac, qgis-2.12

Have installed QGIS 2.12 under Mac OS x 10.9 Mavericks. Had problems when I upgraded to OS X 10.10 so reverted back to 10.9. Will QGIS stop working again if I upgrade to OS X 10.12? Anyone have any experiences?

Comment: OS X 10.12 ? El Capitan is OSX 10.11 and there is no known problems with 10.10.x and 10.11

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that QGIS 2.12 does not work on my OSX Yosemite installation. Cannot find why not and did not find others (yet), but just a heads up...